# Magento $_order->getBaseGrandTotal(); decimal issue

Tags: magento

I am using the call

```
$_order->getBaseGrandTotal();
```

to get the order total to send to the payment gateway.

The problem is the result always comes out at 4 decimal places, e.g. `18.0000`.

I have no sales tax and 5 for shipping. I could do a round on the result but I am worried this might create inconsistencies in what the payment and what is stored in magenta.

I have seen some wild fixes for this on the internet but there but be a simple solution in the backend config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the problem I used php **number_format** function

```
$baseGrandTotal = number_format($_order->getBaseGrandTotal(),2);
```